# Example for a strictly contracting map between spheres

Tags: geometry, lipschitz-functions, spherical-geometry, spheres

I am looking for a **non-trivial** example of a map $f:\mathbb{S}^n \to \mathbb{S}^n$ which is $L$-Lipschitz (w.r.t the intrinsic metric on the sphere or the Euclidean one, it does not matter), where $L < 1$.

By non-trivial I mean that $f$ is non-constant. If more "interesting" examples can be constructed, like maps which are not constant on any open subset this would be great.

Note that it's a theorem that the **image of any such map $f$, must be contained in a hemisphere.**

I will also be happy with examples which are only defined on $\mathbb{S}^n\setminus\{ N\}$;

If we remove a non-trivial "interval" from $\mathbb{S}^1$ for instance, it is not hard to construct contracting maps, by "pushing\squeezeing" the remainder towards the "opposite" hemicircle. However, this cannot be done for the domain $\mathbb{S}^1\setminus\{ N\}$ since we will have points which are arbitrarily closed, and it seems no finite "contracting factor" will suffice.

Comment: This is very interesting. Can you give a reference on the fact that the image of $f$ is contained in a hemisphere?

Comment: (pg 7, lemma 2.8) here:https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwixn6Wo5K3SAhXmIcAKHaquAAkQFggfMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.jyu.fi%2Fresearch%2Freports%2Frep100.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE54zII8UH70WIcqJiOOW78_fLPVw&sig2=lBPorG4MXVmxOhBzva7Uag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First reflect a hemisphere onto the other. This has Lipschitz constant $1$. Now it suffices to find an $L$-Lipschitz function from the hemisphere $H$ inside itself, $L<1$.

To achieve this you can do the following: say the hemisphere $H$ is "centered" at the pole $N$. Then:

1. Project orthogonally $H$ on the tangent space to $H$ at $N$. ($1$-Lipschitz)
2. Apply a homotety of factor $L<1$ to the tangent space. ($L$-Lipschitz)
3. Project on the closed ball $\overline B(0,1)$ ($1$-Lipschitz being the projection on a convex set)

After the last step the image of $H$ will be actually contained in $\mathbb S^{n}$, and the composition will be $L$-Lipschitz.

Comment: Thanks! I do not see why the image of the last step would be in $\mathbb{S}^n$. Think about the north pole for instance - its orthogonal projection onto the tangent space is zero, no? Maybe I am missing something here...

Comment: @Asafshachar I meant the affine tangent space, the one that contains the north pole. It is all outside the ball, therefore its projection lies on the sphere